# How to store a symmetric key inside AndroidKeyStore?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, security, keystore

So, I have a PBE inside my Android app. I have also generated a symmetric key using the user provided password. Now I want to store it safely inside AndroidKeyStore

AndroidKeyStore has a function for this: `setKeyEntry (String alias, Key key, char[] password, Certificate[] chain)`
But the thing is that I get an error message when using it:

```
java.security.KeyStoreException: Protection parameters must be specified when importing a symmetric key
```

I checked the `android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java` file (it's used under the hood) and apparently protection parameters should be passed under the hood to a function called `setSecretKeyEntry`. But instead a null is passed, as visible here:

[A picture of AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java code where setSecretKeyEntry method is called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU52t.png)

Anyone have any suggestions on how to solve the problem? Or maybe there are other ways to store keys besides AndroidKeyStore? Any help would be highly appreciated <3

If you guys want to check the AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java code, it's here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/android10-security-release/keystore/java/android/security/keystore/AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java